# cURL returns response but unable to get the same response when tried to access using selenium firefox webdriver

Tags: linux, selenium, curl

I am trying to extract some data from a website from Linux server using Selenium.

When the URL is pinged through cURL, we are able to see the response from the server but when the same URL requested through Selenium Firefox webdriver, we aren't recieving any response for hours.

For eg:- One of the link we are trying to reach is as follows :

http://www.vudu.com/movies/#!content/776990

Can you point out to a possible issue?

Is it common for websites to react this way?

What might be the way to overcome this issue ?

Thanks in advance for help .

**NOTE:-** The websites we are trying to ping , are already whitelisted in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server might be responding differently based upon you User Agent string.  Many extensions allow you to set this, including "User-Agent Switcher for Chrome."

You might also experiment with the Selenium `chromedriver` and look to see exactly what the request is inside the browser.  You can find this by using the "network" tab of the developer tools:

[image]